# Ruby on Rails Display the future date from the database that is closest to today's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, time, future

In my Ruby on Rails application I am building a cinema system.

On index.html.erb what I want to do is make it so that if the film is not yet released it shows the release date (that works) but if it has already been released and there are showings for that film then display the next date and time it is being shown.

Below is the index.html.erb code that I am trying to use to do this but isn't working.

```
<% if not film.release_date.blank? %>
    <% if film.release_date > Date.today %>
        Release Date: <%= film.release_date.strftime("%e %B %Y ") %>
    <% else %>
        Next Showing: 
        <% film.showings.each do |showing| %>
            <% if showing.show_date == Date.today %>
                <%= showing.show_date %><br>    
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adapting the code by @Geoffroy I have been able to do this correctly using .take(1):

```
Next Showing: 
<% film.showings.take(1).each do |showing| %>
        <%= film.showings.select{|s| s.show_date >= Date.today}.sort_by(&:show_date).first.show_date.strftime("%A %e %B %Y") %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Actually, you're doing it wrong, you're taking to to then take the first, of a collection, which is nonsense. My last proposition was a piece of code to completely replace you `each` loop, which is useless when you display only one element

Answer (score 1):

You are restricting your view to today's showing, so maybe this is why you don't see anything.

```
<% if showing.show_date == Date.current %>
    <%= showing.show_date %><br>    
<% end %>
```

Try to change your code to something like:

```
<% film.showings.select{|s| s.show_date >= Date.current}.each do |showing| %>
  <%= showing.show_date %><br>    
<% end %>
```

Or if you really want only the next showing :

```
<%= film.showings.select{|s| s.show_date >= Date.current}.sort_by(&:show_date).first.show_date %>
```

*I used enumerable methods here but if this is database objects you can also use `where` and `order_by`*.

Comment: And maybe use Date.current instead of Date.today, to take into account your configured timezone.

Comment: Both of those display all of the next dates, what I want to do is restrict it to show only the closest, e.g. today's Monday if there's showings on Tuesday, Wednesday, and Thursday I only want Tuesday.

Comment: @benjs.1 read again the second one then, and notice the `first` I inserted after the sort_by

Comment: In your second code, without the .first.show_date it displays: [#<Showing id: 20, show_date: "2015-01-26", show_time: "2000-01-01 11:00:00", film_id: 2, created_at: "2015-01-26 11:23:25", updated_at: "2015-01-26 11:23:25"> for each showing, with the .first it displays: #<Showing:0x59e2d08> for each one, and then with the .show_date it displays the date, e.g. 2015-01-26 for each record in the database. So just restricts what is shown from each record